# MoPub Android - javascript code is not displayed when a Custom network is created

Tags: javascript, android, mopub

I did integrate the mopub sdk to my project, work well

When I create a Custom Network with a simple html code, the ad is displayed correctly:
(mopub example code)

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    font-size: 12px;font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:white}
    .creative_headline {font-size: 18px;}
    .creative_promo {color: green;text-decoration: none;}
</style>
<div>Welcome to mopub!</div>
<div><a href="http://www.shoutem.com">Click here to test ad</a></div>
<div>You can now set up a new campaign to serve other ads.</div>
```

However when I created the banner with the javascript code (Also is a mopub example)

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
var zflag_nid='1577'; 
var zflag_cid='24'; 
var zflag_sid='1'; 
var zflag_width='320'; 
var zflag_height="50"; 
var zflag_sz='16'; </script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://c2.zedo.com/jsc/c2/fo.js"></script>
```

The Ad is not displayed.

Mopub support the javascript/html code?.
How create a custom network?.

Any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: The problem is only for the emulator, On real devices the javascript with animated gifs works fine.